# merge/blend 2 queries if and conditional statement is true

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this wp query...

```
$downloads = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
));
```

But I want to add this to the query if my `$user_admin` condition is true...

```
if ($user_admin)
    $downloads = new WP_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'download_access_rules',
                'value' => 'genpo',
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

So I run this it seems to break my loop, but not cause a fatal error...

```
$downloads = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
));

if ($user_admin) {
    $downloads = new WP_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'download_access_rules',
                'value' => 'genpo',
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

OK my question is essentially this... How do I blend the two `$downloads` variables if the `$user_admin` condition equals true.

But the fastest and correct method of actually going about doing this as my method does not work.

Comment: What do you want to blend? If there were two arrays, you could use array_merge, but you can't merge two objects together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at your code it looks like you could merge the array together and then create the new WP_Query object. From your description I understand that you are saying that you want the queries to be blended into one and not the results of the query blended into one.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);

if ($user_admin) {
    $args = array_merge($args, array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'download_access_rules',
                'value' => 'genpo',
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    ));
}

$downloads = new WP_Query($args);
```

I also was wondering you indicated that your current code seems to break your loop. Exactly what is happening with your first code example. Are you getting a blank page or simply not having any articles returned?

Another thing to note when checking if a user is an administrator you can also use [is_admin()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) instead of $user_admin.

[Function Reference/is admin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin)

Comment: Thanks @IntegrityFirst this is perfect. Actually I am using current_user_can('media') for the var $user_admin so should be $user_media not $user_admin. I worked out why my loop was not breaking, just that the meta query was wrong and was returning nothing :/ Again thanks works a charm :-)

Comment: Don't need `array_merge` etc for this. Just add to the original `$args` based on the IF condition.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'download',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 20
);


if ($user_admin) {
    $query2 = array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'download_access_rules',
                'value' => 'genpo',
                'compare' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );

   $query = array_merge($query, $query2);
}

$downloads = new WP_Query($query);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you array_merge is just what I am after. Thanks for answer but I will go with @IntegrityFirst answer below because it's slightly shorter hand. But in printable both answers work the same. Really appreciate your time thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I personally prefer putting the array in a separate variable because it looks cleaner and easier to maintain over time. Especially when you have more than 2 arrays. Cheers!

Comment: Yani you do have a point. That's great to know that I can pass multiple vars like that in merge array. But I will check out the php docs more on merge_array for future